# How to explode a range of values in a single row in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
x         frames_start  frames_stop
0         7729.00      7731.00
1         7732.00      7735.00
2         7736.00      7737.00
```

`x` represents a category of data occurring for a certain number of video frames. `frames_start` and `frames_stop` represent all the frames, or time, during which the category occurs. How do I explode each row so that it shows every frame, instead of the range, like this?

```
x        frames
0         7729.00  
0         7730.00     
0         7731.00
1         7732.00
1         7733.00
1         7734.00
1         7735.00
2         7736.00
2         7737.00
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If small data or performance is not important use `range` for new column with [`DataFrame.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html):

```
f = lambda x: range(int(x['frames_start']), int(x['frames_stop']) + 1)
df['frames'] = df.apply(f, axis=1)
df = df.explode('frames')[['x','frames']]
print (df)
   x frames
0  0   7729
0  0   7730
0  0   7731
1  1   7732
1  1   7733
1  1   7734
1  1   7735
2  2   7736
2  2   7737
```

Or repeat index values by subtract both column in [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with [`Index.repeat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.repeat.html) and add new values by counter in [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
df = df.loc[df.index.repeat(df['frames_stop'].sub(df['frames_start']).add(1))]

df['frames'] = df.groupby(level=0).cumcount().add(df['frames_start'])

df = df[['x','frames']]
print (df)
   x  frames
0  0  7729.0
0  0  7730.0
0  0  7731.0
1  1  7732.0
1  1  7733.0
1  1  7734.0
1  1  7735.0
2  2  7736.0
2  2  7737.0
```